# How to trigger a job in SQL based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a job named "job daily" in SQL Developer.

I need to trigger the job 10 minutes after the following conditions are satisfied:

```
Condition - (status = parse complete and finished_date = sysdate)
```

For example,if the above mentioned condition is satisfied at 9 am, the job needs to run at 9:10 am.

What should be done to achieve this?

Comment: you can use dateadd function to adding 10 mintues...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name,  the link only tells me how to create a job.In my case I have already created a job.Question is- job should run exactly after 10 minutes when  conditions mentioned in my question are satisfied.

Comment: You could create a trigger on whetever table has the status and finished_date columns that you are checking.